# Why is it Endodontic (-ic suffix) but Dental (-al suffix)?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, word-formation

Especially when they both derive from Endodontist and Dentist respectively, so context doesn't vary much.

I found many answers on the web explaining that -ic and -ical suffixes don't follow any rule as such and that -ology words tend to favour -ical and never use -ic, but the -al suffix is largely ignored in most discussions.

Comment: _Dental_ does not derive from _dentist_ – where did you get that idea? Both are Latin words derived from _dēns_, but they are separate derivations.

Comment: I see! Then is there no particular rule/reason for these suffixes being different? And thanks!

Comment: They’re both productive derivational suffixes in Latin – as with most productive suffixes, they both carry an awful lot of very broad and specific meanings that intersect in very complex ways. Why two words with those meanings were derived using those particular suffixes is probably not something we can ever know – possibly even the (pre-)Latin speakers who first coined them didn’t even really know themselves.

Comment: Thanks! :) I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective-forming suffix *-al* is originally from Latin (in the form *-alis*). The adjective-forming suffix *-ic* existed originally in both Latin (in the form *-icus*) and in Greek (in the form *-ικός*), but Greek *-ικός* was used more freely to form new adjectives than Latin *-icus*. So a large proportion of *-ic* words are from Greek, while a smaller proportion of *-al* words are from Greek. (The combined suffix *-ical* developed later as an extension of *-ic,* so like *-ic,* *-ical* also tends to occur in words with a Greek origin.)

*Dental* is built on the Latin word for tooth, *dens* (with the stem *dent-*), while *endodontic* is built on the Greek word for tooth, ὀδούς (with the stem *odont-*).

Answer (score 0):

Dental does not derive from Dentist but they both derive from the root 'dens'.

There is no specific reason for the suffixes being different here, because languages are too complex and each suffix has multiple meanings.